# How to implement Google maps with Angular 2?

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am looking for possible solution to implement google maps with Angular 2. I found certain packages to use but all have certain limitations. I tried 'angular2-google-maps' and 'ng2-map' but there are certain things yet to come. Can you please suggest which one is the best to use to implement Google Maps in my application?

PS: I am trying out Google Maps JavaScript APIs but seems like I am facing difficulties to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

there is a project which provides exactly what you need:

https://angular-maps.com/

There is a getting started and it is hosted on github as well:

https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps

Another possibility is it to use the GoogleJSAPI from Google directly. Since Angular2 is JavaScript you can easely add it like described by Google:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=de

Hope this helps,
Cheers